# frequent SQLNet break errors from Oracle AQ Java consumer connections

Tags: java, oracle, jms, oracle-aq

our DBA noticed a lot of SQLNet break errors attributed to connections made from Oracle AQ Java processes that drain these queues.  I don't see any errors on the Java side and it seems to work fine otherwise.  Is there anything about our approach that would cause these breaks?

here is the error from the DB side...using Oracle version 11.2.0.3

```
ORA 25228
25228, 00000, "timeout or end-of-fetch during message dequeue from %s.%s"
// *Cause: User-specified dequeue wait time has passed or the end of the
//         queue has been reached but no message has been retrieved.
// *Action: Try dequeue again with the appropriate WAIT_TIME or the
//          FIRST_MESSAGE option.
```

here is how we initialize our Java AQ connection/session...

```
private static Queue queue = null;

public void init() { 
  QueueConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory = AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(server, schema,    1521, "thin");
  QueueConnection queueConnection = queueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(user, password);
  queueConnection.start();
  QueueSession queueSession = queueConnection.createQueueSession(true, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
  queue = ((AQjmsSession )queueSession).getQueue(streamUser, streamQueue);
 }
```

then with a timer (every 15s), we periodically call this block to drain the queue...

```
QueueReceiver qr = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);

while (true) {
  Message message = qr.receive(1000);
  if(message == null) {
    break;
  } else {
    //process the msg
    queueSession.commit();
  }
}
```

I also took a look at using the onMessage() asynchronous callback approach, but we preferred this approach for various reasons...

Question #1

though this was an example referenced in Oracle's AQ documentation and it seems like a pretty straightforward approach, is there a more stable way of dequeueing messages in Java?

Question #2

also, I'm wondering if the CLIENT_ACK mode could be the culprit...should I be explicitly calling `message.acknowledge()` or does the `queueSession.commit()` cover this?

Answer (score 0):

after some research, this sounds like a bug in Oracle AQ's dequeue and is thrown whenever a queue is empty

references:

- http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_25228.htm
- http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/oracle/bipack/ch05_07.htm

which should then just be caught and ignored, like this:

```
   ...
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         IF SQLCODE = -25228 /* Timeout; queue is likely empty... */
         THEN
            item := NULL;
         ELSE  
            RAISE;
         END IF;
```